# Use freshdesk feedback widget in React.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use Freshdesk's feedback widget in my React.js application. I am trying to initialize and show the widget in my root component's `componentDidMount` method as follows

```
var App = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    FreshWidget.init("", {"queryString": "&widgetType=popup", "utf8": "✓", "widgetType": "popup", "buttonType": "text", "buttonText": "Support", "buttonColor": "white", "buttonBg": "#006063", "alignment": "4", "offset": "235px", "formHeight": "500px", "url": "<myfreshdeskurl>"} );
    FreshWidget.show();
  }
});
```

The widget is not getting displayed and the following error is thrown in the console

```
Freshdesk Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at f (http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js:1:4741)
at http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js:1:6412
at e (http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js:1:38)
at Object.C.show (http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js:1:6392)
at React.createClass.componentDidMount (http://localhost:2345/:14673:15)
at CallbackQueue.assign.notifyAll (http://localhost:2345/:102289:22)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.ON_DOM_READY_QUEUEING.close (http://localhost:2345/:115822:26)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.closeAll (http://localhost:2345/:119697:25)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (http://localhost:2345/:119638:16)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (http://localhost:2345/:113776:15)
```

Comment: Receiving the same issue on my application that uses AngularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass another property in the FreshWidget.init options object:

```
FreshWidget.init("", {"loadOnEvent": 'immediate',...});
```

Otherwise the widget will wait for window.load which has already happened.

Also make sure to wait until html2canvas has been loaded when using the screenshot option, otherwise you will get another error:

```
function showWhenHTML2CanvasIsAvailable() {
    if (window.html2canvas) {
        window.FreshWidget.show();
    } else {
        setTimeout(showWhenHTML2CanvasIsAvailable, 100);
    }
}

showWhenHTML2CanvasIsAvailable();
```